# CFBundleShortVersionString Preventing Upload to App Store

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, version

I am trying to upload a new build to the App Store. My previous build was approved and awaiting manual release but I discovered a few bugs and want to upload a corrected version.

The previous version was 1.0 and build 7.

I am now trying to upload version 1.0 build 8.

The highest build on the App store is the approved build 7 and it is called 1.0

However when I try to upload the archive from Xcode, I am getting the error:

> This bundle is invalid.  The value for key CFBundleShortVersionString
>   [1.0] in the Info.plistfile must contain a higher version than that of
>   the previously approved version [1.0].

When I look in the info.plist file, I see the attached.

[image]

Apple seems to be saying they want me to upload a higher version than 1.0.  Is this because I have an approved version awaiting manual release?  Or what do they want.

Can't I just upload a higher build leaving the version of 1.0 alone?  What does Apple want me to do?  Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: If 1.0 hadn't yet been approved, you could have withdrawn it from review, uploaded a higher build and resubmitted it for review. Since 1.0 has been approved you must move to a higher version, even though you never released 1.0

Comment: I was able to cancel the pending developer release version.  It now shows Developer Rejected instead of pending developer release.  After that I was able to upload the new file successfully. It currently shows processing.  Will see what happens from here...